# Get remote data with inputb text form before

Tags: php

I hope you can understand my problem reading only a fragment of my code.

I will explain what I am doing: I want using a head to write the URL and below a PHP code to open the webpage

HOW I CREATE A VARIABLE?

```
  <form id=url type=get action='DATAPHP.PHP' accept-charset='UTF-8'  >
  <input type=text name=url size=50 value="" ><br><br>
  <input type=submit name=url  value="Enter Url">

  </form>

<?php


$url = '';

$url = $_POST['url'];


echo get_remote_data($url,true); // FOLLOWLOCATION enabled; simple request; 

?>
```

How I fix this code?

Comment: You could try using file_get_contents($url). That is: echo file_get_contents($url)

Comment: Question unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass information from html or a webpage to php is via forms. I'll show you probably the best way to do this first of all, and that's with separate pages for the html and php, then I'll modify the answer so that you can put all the code - the browser output (that's the html) and the php processing on the same page, if that's how you prefer to do it.

First of all, using separate pages:

Let's say you have a form like this in 'basicForm.html':

```
    <form method="post" action="server_processing.php">
        Name:  <input type="text" name="nameInForm"> 
        URL: <input type ="text" name="urlInForm">

       <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

And once a user submits the form the 'server_processing.php' page will receive the values in the form as the POST array, which you can access like so:

```
    <?php
          if($_POST){// this checks for the existence of the $_POST array    
             //now we're assuming a form was submitted
             $nameInForm = $_POST['name'];
             $urlInForm  = $_POST['url'];

             echo ("Name entered: " . $nameInForm);
             echo ("URL entered: " . $urlInForm);
          }// if($_POST)...
     ?>
```

Or you could simply do it all on one page (though separating the code will make code re-use and maintainability easier further down the line):

```
 <form>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="nameInForm"> 
    URL: <input type ="text" name="urlInForm">

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>        

 <?php
    if($_POST){// this checks for the existence of the $_POST array    
         //now we're assuming a form was submitted
         $nameInForm = $_POST['name'];
         $urlInForm  = $_POST['url'];

         echo ("Name entered: " . $nameInForm);
         echo ("URL entered: " . $urlInForm);
    }// if($_POST)...
 ?>
```